# Using .controller to call data between frames in tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm so sorry that this is long but I'm beating my head against a wall here.

As a learning project, I'm building a 3-page `tkinter` app.

I have built an overarching GUI in one `.py` file and the other two pages are in their own files. I want to be able to pass some data (a `tk.StringVar()`) from the front page to the second page and call functions from my `GUI.py` class on each page.

I have been hunting for an answer for this and I've found options for helping to structure each file so that I don't have one long file, @Bryan Oakley and @Reblochon Masque have been incredibly helpful even following their answers on other similar questions but I'm still just not understanding this.

This is the code for the overarching GUI

```
import tkinter as tk
import front_page
import main_page


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        # Initialize Window
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        pages = (front_page.FrontPage, main_page.GamePage)
        # Load all pages
        for F in pages:
            frame = F(container, self, pages)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(front_page.FrontPage)

        self.show_frame(front_page.FrontPage)

    # shows the desired frame
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        return True

    # passes text to the window StartPage
    def pass_on_text(self, text):
        self.frames[front_page.FrontPage].get_text(text)


app = GUI()
app.geometry("400x600")
app.mainloop()
```

This is the code from the frontpage:

```
import tkinter as tk
import main_page




class FrontPage(tk.Frame):
    """This is a class to make the front page
    it inherits from tk.Frame
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, pages):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller



        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.name_label = tk.Label(
            self.mainframe,
            text="Welcome agent:",
            font=("Courier", 20),
        )
        self.name_label.pack()

        self.inst_label1 = tk.Label(
            self.mainframe,
            text="Agent's name:",
            font=("Courier", 15),
            bd=20,
        )
        self.inst_label1.place(
            relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor="n"
        )

        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(
            self.mainframe,
            justify=tk.CENTER,
        )
        self.name_entry.place(
            relx=0.5, rely=0.37, anchor="n"
        )

        self.ent_btn = tk.Button(
            self.mainframe,
            text="Save",
            font=("Courier", 15),
            command=lambda: self.send_text(self.name_entry.get()),#this is the problem
        )
        self.ent_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.43, anchor="n")

        self.btn_frame = tk.Frame(
            self.mainframe,
            height=200,
            width=395,
            bd=4,
            relief=tk.GROOVE,
        )
        self.btn_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor="n")

        self.rules_btn = tk.Button(
            self.mainframe,
            text="RULES",
            font=("Courier", 15),
        )
        self.rules_btn.place(
            relx=0.25,
            rely=0.66,
            anchor="n",
            height=120,
            width=170,
        )

        self.con_btn = tk.Button(
            self.mainframe,
            text="DEPLOY",
            font=("Courier", 15),
            justify=tk.CENTER,
            commane = controller.show_frame(controller.frames[1])
        )
        self.con_btn.place(
            relx=0.75,
            rely=0.66,
            anchor="n",
            height=120,
            width=170,
        )
```

so what I want to do is call the `pass_on_text()` function from `GUI.py` as the command in the self.ent_btn in `front_page.py` but every time I make a change  I just get different errors. I'm 90% sure this is because I'm not understanding the role that `self.controller` plays and how to call functions/methods from it or how to properly pass tk.Vars between different frames.

Thanks for any help you can offer. Assume a very small level of knowledge of OOP knowledge.

Comment: If someone could point me to a good tutorial for this I'd be really grateful.

Comment: as I know there is no tutorial for `self.controller`. It is code which probably was create only as answer on Stackoverflow and now all people use this code and they create new questions on Stackoverflow :)